# How to write select query if the condition contains single quotes(')

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I Want to retrive the data from Oracle DB where name contins single quote(')

```
Select * from table_name where name in ('Joel D'Silva','O'neil Dsa');
```

Comment: Removed unwanted *MySQL* tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass string to `q'[]'` in following:

```
Select * from table_name where name in (q'[Joel D'Silva','O'neil Dsa]');
```

or you could use quote `'` twice in following:

```
Select * from table_name where name in ('Joel D''Silva'',''O''neil Dsa');
```

Comment: Your first option is specific to `Mysql` or `Oracle` it didn't work in `SQL Server`

Comment: What does `q` stands for in `q'[]'`

Comment: @Prdp as per OP question It's *Oracle*. `Q` or `q` indicates that the alternative quoting mechanism will be used. This mechanism allows a wide range of delimiters for the text string.

Comment: Thanks, Good to know

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas What is i want to insert the same values will my querry be same 
insert into table_name
  name
values
  ('Joel D''silva','O''neil Dsa');

Comment: @JustCode007 so what's your question? `insert into table_name (name) values ('Joel D''Silva'');`

Answer (score 3):

Replace `'` with `''`:

```
Select * from table_name where name in ('Joel D''Silva','O''neil Dsa');
```